# Too much hot water from bathroom faucet

Tags: faucet

Hoping to get some guidance on what the source of my issue might be:  I have a single handle bathroom sink faucet which provides very hot water when the handle is set for "warm" water.  I tried reducing the incoming hot water by closing the shut off valve about halfway.  Now when I try for warm water I get:

- cool water when the handle is set to full open
- cool to warm when the handle is opened half way
- burning hot when the handle is opened slightly

I have already changed the cartridge in the faucet.  Might the incoming hot water line pressure be too high?  If yes, is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: Is this a new problem? Does any other faucet have the problem? Are both valves open below the sink?

Comment: Not a new problem, but we now have children that use the faucet so we are trying to find a fix.  No other faucets have the problem.  Currently the cold line is fully open, the hot is about halfway open.

Comment: It sounds like the hot and cold supply lines are switched under the sink.

Comment: Since this is a long-term issue, it sounds like the water heater temperature is set too high.

Answer (score 1):

The shutoff valve (or, indeed, water pressure in general) is not a good way to control the hot water temperature.

You either need a faucet with a built-in and correctly functioning (and correctly adjusted, if adjustable) tempering valve (sometimes referred to as an "anti-scald" valve), or you need a tempering valve  on the hot supply to the faucet.

The vast majority of faucets produced in the past 40 or so years have an anti-scald feature built-in, as many countries require that feature in their adopted plumbing code.

One approach is to put a tempering valve for the whole house on the outlet of the water heater.